# comparing one sample t-test, wilcoxon signed rank test, and sign test in a simulation

Tags: self-study

I have a simulation where I am trying to compare the performance of the one sample t-test, wilcoxon signed rank test, and the sign test on simulated data from the t-distribution.

I need to compare $H_0 = 0$ or $H_a \neq 0$ for various sample size and degrees of freedom combination.

However, isn't the wilcoxon signed rank test, and the sign test, meant for paired data? My t distributions that I am using aren't paired in the sense that they are repeated observations taken from the same population, i.e., before and after some treatment. Can I even use the wilcoxon signed rank test, and the sign test, to test the simple hypothesis that I've outlined here?

I should also clarify here that I am trying to test for the **mean** of 0 in my null hypothesis. The t test tests for the mean - while its my understanding that the single sample wilcoxon signed rank test tests for the median.

For the wilcoxon test, is it required to have have two dependent samples? So, for testing on one sample for null mean of 0, wilcoxon would not be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wilcoxon test and the sign test, you just create a second sample in which the null hypothesis value is zero (or whatever the H0 value for mu is) in each case.  Then the differences are computed from the hypothesized mean instead of from a paired observation.

In R, the `wilcox.test` command lets you use a single sample.

Comment: Thanks. I've applied the R wilcox test, but not sure how to interpret what its doing. Is it creating this second sample where the null hypothesis is 0 automatically?

Comment: @user141133 I would actually frame it the other way.  The paired sample Wilcoxon test uses subtraction to reduce the two dependent samples to a single sample of differences, and then tests that single sample for the +/- split around zero based on an assumption of a symmetric distribution of differences.  The t-test for paired samples works in a similar (though parametric) way - it's a single sample test on difference scores with a null hypothesis that the mean of the distribution of difference scores is zero.

Comment: J Taylor -- does this mean that to use the wilcoxon test, you MUST have two dependent samples? So, for testing on one sample for null mean of 0, wilcoxon would not be appropriate?

Comment: @user141133 No - it doesn't mean that.  It means that both the paired-sample t-test and the Wilcoxon signed rank test on dependent samples are really one-sample tests.  So there is no reason they won't work on a single sample.  They only look like they are two-sample tests because they use two samples to generate a single sample of difference scores (in the case of the t-test) or a single sample of signed ranks (in the case of the Wilcoxon).

Comment: You have made some good comments that I think would improve your answer.